# Neo4j cypher query error :Invalid input 'Q': expected 't/T'

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Getting Error (Invalid input 'Q': expected 't/T') while executing matching cypher query in Neo4j.

```
MATCH (company:COMPANY {name:'`X'SQUIRE COMMUNICATIONS PRIVATE LIMITED'}), 
      (cin:CORPORATE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER {number:'U64202TN2001PTC048084'}) 
CREATE (company)-[:IDENTIFIED_BY]-> (cin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is single quote (') in the data. To resolve use double quote instead of single quote(").

```
MATCH (company:COMPANY {name:"`X'SQUIRE COMMUNICATIONS PRIVATE LIMITED"}), 
      (cin:CORPORATE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER {number:'U64202TN2001PTC048084'}) 
CREATE (company)-[:IDENTIFIED_BY]-> (cin)
```